# Docker: Subir arquivo sql grande

Tags: mysql, docker

Pessoal estou tendo problemas com o Docker.
Estou utilizando `Docker` e o `docker-compose` para criar e configurar um ambiente web de forma rápida e prática.
Sou usuário de docker a algum tempo, porém nunca precisei subir um arquivo grande para um bando de dados.
Estou usando `Mysql 5.5` por compatibilidade em alguns de meus projetos.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e descobri que dava para subir um arquivo .sh do host para o container do mysql e lá executar o que eu quisesse, porém sempre obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
mysql: unrecognized service
```

Meu arquivo `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY setup.sh /mysql/setup.sh
COPY setup.sql /mysql/setup.sql
RUN /mysql/setup.sh
```

Meu arquivo `docker-compose.yml`

```
php:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "80:80"
   - "443:443"
  volumes:
   - ./www:/var/www/html
  links:
   - mysql   
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.5
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
```

Este é meu arquivo `setup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
service mysql start
mysql uroot -p1234 my_db < /mysql/setup.sql
service mysql stop
```

Tudo corre bem, o erro acontece na linha do setup.sh: `service mysql start`

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duque, não te serve subir o dump após subir a máquina?
após o start do container, poderia executar por exemplo:

```
docker exec -i CONTAINER mysql -u root --password=1234 my_db < ./MySQLDump.sql
```

Isso resolveria seu problema de uma forma mais simples. Permite que você controle melhor o banco, não precisando subir um dump toda vez que der build.

Comment: Desta forma funcionou perfeitamente, mas somente com arquivos que não tenham linhas comentas com --. Removi os comentários e funcionou.
Mas se eu tiver que remover possíveis comentários toda vez que for subir um arquivo, então vai ficar complicado de mais.
Uma solucão que funcionou perfeitamente sem erros é:
Logar no container em /bin/bash, usar docker cp para copiar o arquivo do HOST para o container e então logar no mysql e subir por lá.

Comment: sério? eu subo dump assim sempre, nunca deu problema. Como você está fazendo o dump?

Comment: Sério! O dump do arquivo SQL que tenho não foi eu quem o fez.